# using BIT as INT for storage volume efficiency

Tags: mysql, casting, int, bit, space-efficiency

If I'm understanding correctly, `BIT` is extremely disk efficient.  For my case, I know I will always only have three values which I'd like to treat like `INT`s: `1`, `2`, & `3`.

Am I correct that `b'00'` is `3` and different from `b'0'`, `1`?

If I try to use `INT` values for `INSERT` `VALUE`s and `SELECT` `WHERE`s, will mysql automatically cast as `BIT`s in those queries?

Comment: This works, but it makes no sense to use a wrong type, when there's [TINYINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html) also taking a single byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into t (bits) values (b'11'); /* 3 = 2^1+2^0 */
insert into t (bits) values (b'10'); /* 2 = 2^1 */
insert into t (bits) values (b'1'); /*  1 = 2^0 */
```

Yes can insert `INT`;